# Not able to create Python virtual env with lesser version than installed

Tags: python, virtualenv, sys.path

I installed Python 3.9.0 recently, and I am using virtualenv package.
While creating a new environment with specifying a lesser python version, say 3.6
I am getting this error:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.6'

I suppose I don't need to download 3.6 specifically to create an environment for that python version.
Can I get around it using just virtualenv package?

Comment: You did not tell us how you tried to create the virtual environment.

Comment: @KlausD. The command i used was: virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6

Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/python3.6'

Comment: You are on Windows and that is not even a Windows path. And BTW addcall relevant information to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to download Python 3.6 in order to use it you could store in an environment but you can't get python 3.6 by creating an environment for it.

Comment: So, if i need another version next time? Do, I need to download each of the version and then create environment based on those version?

Comment: Yes you need to download each version

Comment: yes, I downloaded, configure Paths and now it is running without any issues.